# Conditional selector name with SASS

Tags: css, sass

I want generate classes like `grid-col-1`, `grid-col-md-1`, `grid-col-lg-1`, `grid-col-2`, `grid-col-md-2`, `grid-col-lg-2`...

So, I have created this mixin to do it:

```
$grid-columns: 12;
@mixin grid-col-builder($type: false) {
  @for $i from 1 through $grid-columns {
    $selector: 'grid-col-';
    @if $type { $selector: $selector + $type + '-' + $i; }
    @else { $selector: $selector + $i; }
    .#{$selector} { width: $i/$grid-columns*100%; }
  }
}
```

But I still think the code a bit repetitive. Is there a smarter way to make the condition that adds the type in the selector name?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make things more compact by using the `if()` function:

```
$grid-columns: 12;
@mixin grid-col-builder($type: false) {
  @for $i from 1 through $grid-columns {
    .#{'grid-col-' + if($type, $type + '-', '') + $i} {
        width: $i / $grid-columns * 100%;
    }
  }
}
```